# Firestore writing but not reading

Tags: flutter, firebase-security

i'm getting some error in the read of my firestore data.

[image: Here's my collection]

and i'm using the following rule:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // Allow only authenticated content owners access
    match /Produto/{document} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null &&
      request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.idUsuario
    }
  }
}
```

The app i'm coding its in flutter, i'm new and following some tutorials, i have a streambuilder and its constantly returning null.

```
child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
    stream: _stream,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
        return const Center(child: LoadingCircular());
      }
      return Column(
```

With:

```
final Stream<QuerySnapshot> _stream = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Produto').snapshots();
```

When i'm writing the data goes well, but it's not reading with this rule, when i set the default rule of read works, but i'm trying to read only author data.
Can someone help?

Sorry for my english and knowledge haha, i'm still learning.

Comment: whats your `_stream` value?

Comment: final Stream<QuerySnapshot> _stream =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Produto').snapshots();

Comment: you will have to either specify the document name or add where query in the `_steam` value.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase's [security rules do not filter data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#rules_are_not_filters), but merely check that your code is not requesting any data it doesn't have access to. Since your rules check that `request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.idUsuario`, your code must do the same and pass that as a condition in the query.

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Produto')
  .where('idUsuario', isEqualTo: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid)
  .snapshots();
```

Comment: So i just need to add in my code? Cause i remove the rule to the default and add this .where and it works, with the previous rule didn't, even adding the .where...
Thank you